# resolve of scanning cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

hi i want to do one tutorial named bluetoothChat from google but i get this kind of erros:

scanning cannot be resolved or is not a field-for line-setTitle(R.string.scanning);

> id cannot be resolved or is not a
>   field
>   -for line-findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

how can i solve this kind of errors

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors means that your linked resources cannot be found in the xml files.

Did you take a look in the [res-folder](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/res/index.html) of the project?